Why does passing a dict into pd.DataFrame() generate an empty dataframe?
I have a dict like this:
{'id': '123', 'sales_attributes': [], 'seller_sku': '123'}
I want to generate a dataframe to store it.When I use pd.DataFrame(), it's generate a empty dataframe

When I use pd.json_normalize(), I got the desired results

Why? Can anyone help me?

You have to wrap everything in lists:
dic = {'id': ['123'], 'sales_attributes': [[]], 'seller_sku': ['123']}
print(pd.DataFrame(dic))

    id sales_attributes seller_sku
0  123               []        123

Why?
When you pass a dictionary to the DataFrame constructor it expected lists as items, with all lists having the same length:
dic = {'id': ['123', '456'], 'seller_sku': ['123', '456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

    id seller_sku
0  123        123
1  456        456

As a convenience, you can also pass literals and they will be expanded to all rows:
dic = {'id': ['123', '456'], 'seller_sku': ['123', '456'], 'other': 'X'}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

    id seller_sku other
0  123        123     X
1  456        456     X

Any other format would fail, such as uneven lists or only literals:
dic = {'id': ['123', '456'], 'seller_sku': ['123']}
print(pd.DataFrame(dic))
# ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

dic = {'id': '123', 'seller_sku': '123'}
print(pd.DataFrame(dic))
# ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

In your case, there is one attribute defining the number of rows (0) and 2 literals, so the output is an empty DataFrame:
dic = {'id': '123', 'sales_attributes': [], 'seller_sku': '123'}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, sales_attributes, seller_sku]
Index: []


I think you mean "scalar" instead of "literal"

although the documentation calls them "constants": "Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects."

@juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, that's a very valid point. I tried to edit the answer to replace "literals" by "scalar/constants", unfortunately it failed (I get "An error occurred submitting the edit.", maybe due to this bug). Would you mind trying to edit it?
